# How do I render HTML returned from a filter in django template?

Tags: html, django, markdown

I have a md file which needs to be converted into html (for blog website). The filter (markdownify) converts md file into html tags. Now, html tags are shown on the website.
How do I render this html on website (in django template).

Is there any filter to do so?
Or is there any other method to convert md into html in django?

Code ->

```
<p>{{ post.body | markdownify }}</p>
```

md file ->

```
### h1 header

*jh*

* sdfs
* ksdjfh
*  skdjkfhsk

[link] (#)
```

The output in web page:

```
h1 header
<em>jh</em>

sdfs
ksdjfh
skdjkfhsk
[link] (#)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding below code in the settings.py solved the problem. HTML tags are not shown on rendered web page now.

```
MARKDOWNIFY_WHITELIST_TAGS = {
 'a', 'p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3','h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'h7', 'ul', 'li', 'span', 'img', 'div', 'abbr', 'acronym', 'em', 'blockquote', 'i', 'strong', 'ol', 'b', 'code'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try
`{{ post.body | markdownify | safe }}`.
The safe filter disables any further HTML escaping. Read more about the filter in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe).

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. The output is still the same. Thanks a lot for your answer!