# Markdowned content not reflected in my html template (<em><strong>)

Tags: html, django, cs50

In my Django project, I am using markdownify to convert my markdown to HTML.
I have a problem while rendering the HTML content to my template.

some tags like `<em>`, `<strong>` are not getting reflected.
I have tried using the safe filter as suggested in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63618820/how-do-i-render-html-returned-from-a-filter-in-django-template?answertab=active#tab-top) but I find no changes!

Is there any other filter I can use or any method to render correctly

in settings.py

```
MARKDOWNIFY = {
  "default": {
        "STRIP": True,
        "BLEACH": True,
        "MARKDOWNIFY_LINKIFY_TEXT": True,
        "WHITELIST_TAGS": [
            'a',
            'abbr',
            'acronym',
            'b',
            'blockquote',
            'em',
            'i',
            'li',
            'ol',
            'p',
            'strong',
            'ul'
        ],
        "WHITELIST_ATTRS": [
            'href',
            'src',
            'alt',
        ],
        "WHITELIST_STYLES": [
            'color',
            'font-weight',
        ],
        "LINKIFY_TEXT": {
            "PARSE_URLS": True,
            "PARSE_EMAIL": True,
            "CALLBACKS": [],
            "SKIP_TAGS": ['pre', 'code',],
        },
         "WHITELIST_PROTOCOLS": [
            'http',
            'https',
        ],
        "MARKDOWN_EXTENSIONS": [
            'markdown.extensions.fenced_code',
            'markdown.extensions.extra',
            
        ]
  },
}
```

in my template:

```
<div class="col-8">
    {{ entry|markdownify|safe }}
</div>
```

the content:

```
#This is the H1 tag for Heading

but these are working

- paragraph

- all the headers

- list tag

things not getting converted

- *Italics not working*

- **And also bold text**
```

In my template,this is what i get

```
This is the H1 tag for Heading
but these are working

paragraph

all the headers

list tag

things not getting converted

<em>Italics not working</em>

<strong>And also bold text</strong>
```

**Images for reference:**

- [content to be markdowned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGX2S.png)
- [final outcome that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hWoP.png)